# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined" when triggered a function

Tags: javascript

**EDIT: I found that the code is working fine and nothing is wrong. It's myself that was blurred. Sorry for not being cautious.**

I have a HTML file with a form containing a textbox with ID #StuIDtxt.

Also there is a few JavaScript, and here is a code in my file. The function getResult() would be triggered when the form is submitted.

```
function getResult(){
  var StuID = document.getElementById('StuIDtxt').value;
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result[StuID].Name;
  return false;
}
```

There is also a variable name 'result' storing array parsed from JSON.

When I fill the textbox with '10001' and submit the form, JavaScript console said

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
```

However typing

```
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result['10001'].Name;
```

in console result in successful execution as expected.

Did I do anything wrong in the function?

Live web here: https://srakrn.com/satitnpru/announce

Comment: Just as a test, can you do `console.log(StuID);` and `console.log(result);` in your `getResult` function?  Chances are one of those two things is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON retrieved from `https://srakrn.com/satitnpru/announce/result_demo.json` does not contain any id of `10001`. If I try `00001` the error does not occur. Change like this:

```
function getResult(){
  var StuID = document.getElementById('StuIDtxt').value;
  if ( StuID != null && StuID.trim() != "" )
  {
       if ( typeof result[StuID] != "undefined" )
           document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result[StuID].Name;
       else
           alert("Unknonw ID: " + StuID);
  }
  return false;
}
```

In your code, you assume that the given ID will always exist in `result` and directly reference `Name`. In case, `StuID` doesn't exist, this will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because '10001' doesn't exist

here is the log from the `result` var

http://prntscr.com/9mdsjv

I used '00020' and its OK